# Draw outline circle with sdl2

Tags: python, graphics, transparency, sdl-2, pysdl2

**TL;DR:** Using (py)sdl2, I am trying to draw a circle outline of which the interior is transparent and thus shows objects drawn behind it. Basically I need to find a way to erase the pixels of the interior of a filled circle (or draw them over with/set them back to transparent pixels). I'd like to use Textures instead of Surfaces, as far as this is possible.

I am trying to achieve something that seems conceptually very simple, but I just can't make it happen.

I want to draw a circle outline with sdl2 in python. Of course, this is very simple to achieve with the sdl2gfx function `circleRGBA()`, but it only allows you to draw outlines with a line width of 1px. It seems downright impossible to draw circles with thicker outlines.

I have done something like this before with pygame surfaces using transparent color keys ([inspired by this method](https://github.com/expyriment/expyriment/blob/master/expyriment/stimuli/_ellipse.py#L155-L178)), and I know surfaces are also available in SDL2, but the *caveat* is that I'm trying to stick to the much faster textures, which do not provide the color key mechanism.

To explain things a bit better visually: what I'm trying to achieve is:

[image: The goal]

a circle (annulus) larger than 1px wide of which the interior is transparent, such that items drawn behind the circle will be visible in the interior.

A trick that I have used in the past is to just draw 2 filled circles, where a second smaller circle has the same color as the background. However, this obscures everything behind the circle (in this case the white line). Here's an example of a function using this approach:

```
@to_texture
def draw_circle(self, x, y, r, color, opacity=1.0, fill=True, aa=False, penwidth=1):
    # Make sure all spatial parameters are ints
    x, y, r = int(x), int(y), int(r)
    # convert color parameter to sdl2 understandable values
    color = sdl2.ext.convert_to_color(color)
    # convert possible opacity values to the right scale
    opacity = self.opacity(opacity)
    # Get background color set for this texture
    bgcolor = self.__bgcolor

    # Check for invalid penwidth values, and make sure the value is an int
    if penwidth != 1:
        if penwidth < 1:
            raise ValueError("Penwidth cannot be smaller than 1")
        if penwidth > 1:
            penwidth = int(penwidth)

    # if the circle needs to be filled, it's easy
    if fill:
        sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
    else:
        # If penwidth is 1, simple use sdl2gfx own functions
        if penwidth == 1:
            if aa:
                sdlgfx.aacircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
            else:
                sdlgfx.circleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
        else:
            # If the penwidth is larger than 1, things become a bit more complex.
            outer_r = int(r+penwidth*.5)
            inner_r = int(r-penwidth*.5)

            # Draw outer circle
            sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y,
                outer_r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)

            # Draw inner circle
            sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y,
                inner_r, bgcolor.r, bgcolor.g, bgcolor.b, 255)

    return self
```

Resulting in:

[image: First attempt]

I also tried playing around with various blending modes, and this was the best result I could get:

```
@to_texture
def draw_circle(self, x, y, r, color, opacity=1.0, fill=True, aa=False, penwidth=1):

        # ... omitted for brevity

        else:
            # If the penwidth is larger than 1, things become a bit more complex.
            # To ensure that the interior of the circle is transparent, we will
            # have to work with multiple textures and blending.
            outer_r = int(r+penwidth*.5)
            inner_r = int(r-penwidth*.5)

            # Calculate the required dimensions of the separate texture we are
            # going to draw the circle on. Add 1 pixel to account for division
            # inaccuracies (i.e. dividing an odd number of pixels)
            (c_width, c_height) = (outer_r*2+1, outer_r*2+1)

            # Create the circle texture, and make sure it can be a rendering
            # target by setting the correct access flag.
            circle_texture = self.environment.texture_factory.create_sprite(
                size=(c_width, c_height),
                access=sdl2.SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET
            )

            # Set renderer target to the circle texture
            if sdl2.SDL_SetRenderTarget(self.sdl_renderer, circle_texture.texture) != 0:
                raise Exception("Could not set circle texture as rendering"
                    " target: {}".format(sdl2.SDL_GetError()))

            # Draw the annulus:
            # as the reference point is the circle center, outer_r
            # can be used for the circles x and y coordinates.
            sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, outer_r, outer_r,
                outer_r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)

            # Draw the hole
            sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, outer_r, outer_r,
                inner_r, 0, 0, 0, 255)

            # Set renderer target back to the FrameBuffer texture
            if sdl2.SDL_SetRenderTarget(self.sdl_renderer, self.surface.texture) != 0:
                raise Exception("Could not unset circle texture as rendering"
                    " target: {}".format(sdl2.SDL_GetError()))

            # Use additive blending when blitting the circle texture on the main texture
            sdl2.SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(circle_texture.texture, sdl2.SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD)

            # Perform the blitting operation
            self.renderer.copy( circle_texture, dstrect=(x-int(c_width/2),
                y-int(c_height/2), c_width, c_height) )

    return self
```

which results in:

[image: Second attempt with blending]

Close, but no cigar, as the line now appears to be *in front* of the circle instead of behind it, and as far as I understand additive/screen blending, this is the intended behavior.

I know there is also the function [SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode), but the sdl2gfx drawing functions seem to ignore anything you set with this function.

Is there anyone with more experience than me who has done something like this before and who can point me in the right direction on how to tackle this challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create a `SDL_Surface`, create a software renderer for it, draw on it, use `SDL_ColorKey()` to get rid of the inner color, then convert it back to `SDL_Texture`. Maybe it's not the fastest way but it works. You can always create a transparent PNG image and load from it.

```
import sys
import ctypes
from sdl2 import *
import sdl2.sdlgfx as sdlgfx

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              200, 200, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED)


    ############################################################
    surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 200, 200, 32,
                                   0xff000000, # r mask
                                   0x00ff0000, # g mask
                                   0x0000ff00, # b mask
                                   0x000000ff) # a mask
    soft_renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface)

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(soft_renderer, 255, 255, 0, 255) #yellow background
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(soft_renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE)
    SDL_RenderClear(soft_renderer)
    sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(soft_renderer, 100, 100, 100, 0, 255, 255, 255)
    sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(soft_renderer, 100, 100,  80, 255, 255, 0, 255) #yellow
    SDL_SetColorKey(surface, SDL_TRUE, 0xffff00ff) #yellow colorkey

    circ = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface)

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(soft_renderer)
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface)
    ############################################################

    running = True
    event = SDL_Event()
    while running:
        # Event loop
        while SDL_PollEvent(ctypes.byref(event)) != 0:
            if event.type == SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        # Rendering
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255)
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer)
        sdlgfx.thickLineRGBA(renderer, 200, 0, 0, 200, 10, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, circ, None, None)
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(circ)
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer)
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window)
    SDL_Quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right in that it's the only way. You just beat me to it: I also solved the problem in a similar way, and will post my solution here too. Still though, you have a more complete and comprehensive example which deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: The code works! But I had some problems. To solve them, I installed this package: `pip install pysdl2-dll` and added `b` before "Test" here: `SDL_CreateWindow(b"Test"`) to run it with Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

@tntxtnt just beat me to it, but I solved this problem myself in a similar fashion. My solution also doesn't meet the demand to only use textures, and does fall back to using surfaces. I don't know if it is possible to solve this problem using only textures, or if using surfaces will have a large impact on performance, but at least this works.

@tntxtnt solution is very good, but I'll add mine here too since I have a slightly different approach by relying a bit more on pysdl2's utility functions:

```
class FrameBuffer(object):

    # ... omitted for brevity

    @to_texture
    def draw_circle(self, x, y, r, color, opacity=1.0, fill=True, aa=False, penwidth=1):
        # Make sure all spatial parameters are ints
        x, y, r = int(x), int(y), int(r)

        # convert color parameter to sdl2 understandable values
        color = sdl2.ext.convert_to_color(color)
        # convert possible opacity values to the right scale
        opacity = self.opacity(opacity)

        # Check for invalid penwidth values, and make sure the value is an int
        if penwidth != 1:
            if penwidth < 1:
                raise ValueError("Penwidth cannot be smaller than 1")
            if penwidth > 1:
                penwidth = int(penwidth)

        # if only a filled circle needs to be drawn, it's easy
        if fill:
            sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
        else:
            # If penwidth is 1, simply use sdl2gfx's own functions
            if penwidth == 1:
                if aa:
                    sdlgfx.aacircleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
                else:
                    sdlgfx.circleRGBA(self.sdl_renderer, x, y, r, color.r, color.g, color.b, opacity)
            else:
                # If the penwidth is larger than 1, things become a bit more complex.
                # To ensure that the interior of the circle is transparent, we will
                # have to work with multiple textures and blending.
                outer_r, inner_r = int(r+penwidth*.5), int(r-penwidth*.5)

                # Calculate the required dimensions of the extra texture we are
                # going to draw the circle on. Add 1 pixel to account for division
                # errors (i.e. dividing an odd number of pixels)
                c_width, c_height = outer_r*2+1, outer_r*2+1

                # Create the circle texture, and make sure it can be a rendering
                # target by setting the correct access flag.
                circle_sprite = self.environment.texture_factory.create_software_sprite(
                    size=(c_width, c_height),
                )
                # Create a renderer to draw to the circle sprite
                sprite_renderer = sdl2.ext.Renderer(circle_sprite)

                # Determine the optimal color key to use for this operation
                colorkey_color = self.determine_optimal_colorkey(color, self.background_color)

                # Clear the sprite with the colorkey color
                sprite_renderer.clear(colorkey_color)

                # Draw the annulus:
                sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(sprite_renderer.sdlrenderer, outer_r, outer_r,
                    outer_r, color.r, color.g, color.b, 255)
                # Antialias if desired
                if aa:
                    for i in range(-1,1):
                        for j in range(2):
                            sdlgfx.aacircleRGBA(sprite_renderer.sdlrenderer, outer_r,
                                outer_r, outer_r+i, color.r, color.g, color.b, 255)

                # Draw the hole
                sdlgfx.filledCircleRGBA(sprite_renderer.sdlrenderer, outer_r, outer_r,
                    inner_r, colorkey_color.r, colorkey_color.g, colorkey_color.b, 255)
                # Antialias if desired
                if aa:
                    for i in range(0,2):
                        for j in range(2):
                            sdlgfx.aacircleRGBA(sprite_renderer.sdlrenderer, outer_r,
                                outer_r, inner_r+i, color.r, color.g, color.b, 255)

                # Optimize drawing of transparent pixels
                sdl2.SDL_SetSurfaceRLE(circle_sprite.surface, 1)

                # Convert the colorkey to a format understandable by the 
                # SDL_SetColorKey function
                colorkey = sdl2.SDL_MapRGB(circle_sprite.surface.format, 
                    colorkey_color.r, colorkey_color.g, colorkey_color.b)

                # Set transparency color key
                sdl2.SDL_SetColorKey(circle_sprite.surface, sdl2.SDL_TRUE, colorkey)

                # Create a texture from the circle sprite
                circle_texture = self.environment.texture_factory.from_surface(
                    circle_sprite.surface
                )

                # Set the desired transparency value to the texture
                sdl2.SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(circle_texture.texture, opacity)

                # Perform the blitting operation
                self.renderer.copy( circle_texture, dstrect=(x-int(c_width/2),
                    y-int(c_height/2), c_width, c_height) )

                # Cleanup
                del(circle_sprite)
                del(sprite_renderer)

        return self

    def determine_optimal_colorkey(self, drawing_color, dev_offset=5):
        """ Determines the optimal color to use for the transparent color key."""

        # If foreground and background colors are not identical, simply return
        # the background color
        if drawing_color != self.background_color:
            return self.background_color

        if not 1 <= dev_offset <= 25:
            raise ValueError("dev_offset should be a value between 1 and 25")

        # Create offset_color
        offset_color = sdl2.ext.Color(dev_offset, dev_offset, dev_offset, 0)
        # Create white_color
        white = sdl2.ext.Color(255,255,255,255)

        color_key = self.background_color + offset_color
        if color_key != white:
            return color_key
        else:
            return self.background_color - offset_color

    def opacity(self, value):
        """ Convert float values to opacity range between 0 and 255. """
        if type(value) == float and 0.0 <= value <= 1.0:
            # This is maybe a bit iffy, because it does not allow opacity values
            # in the 0 to 255 range between 0 and 1 (it maybe undesiredly converts
            # it to value*255).
            # TODO: Think about a solution for this
            return int(value*255)
        elif type(value) in [int, float]:
            if 0 <= value <= 255:
                return int(value)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid opacity value")
        else:
            raise TypeError("Incorrect type or value passed for opacity.")

    # ... ommitted for brevity
```